# How can a Activity/Window get the text of another Activity/Window?

Tags: android

I want make a live dictionary app.

Can a Activity/Window get the text of another Activity/Window ?

Is it possible ?

P.S. this app will works for all other apps in the phone, so I cannot insert code to other apps. I mean get text without the help of the target apps. When two apps running, user touch one app and the other app get the text that been touched.

Comment: have you found a solution - to get touched text from other app/activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in two way.
one is getting required value from bundle and second is by using sharedPreferences.

// using bundle

in 1st activity -

```
    String user_id = "abcd";
    Intent intent_msg = new Intent(this, 2nd activity.class);
    Bundle bundle_msg = new Bundle();
    bundle_msg.putString("user_id", user_id);
    intent_msg.putExtras(bundle_msg);
    startActivity(intent_msg);
```

in 2nd activity -

// inside onCreate

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String user_id = bundle.getString("user_id");
```

// using SharedPreferences

1st activity -

```
    Editor editor= getSharedPreferences("userId", 0).edit();
    editor.putString("userId", user_id);
    editor.commit();
```

2nd activity -

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("userId", 1);
    String user_id = pref.getString("userId", "");
```

try it.

Answer (score 0):

**Activity1.**

```
//Create 1 Bundle and send with Intent
Bundle sendBundle = new Bundle();
sendBundle.putLong("value", value);

// Intent to start Activity2 và and attach sendBundble
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtras(sendBundle);
    startActivity(i);

//exit Activity1
finish();
```

**Activity2.**

```
Bundle receiveBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
final long receiveValue = receiveBundle.getLong("value");

receiveValueEdit.setText(String.valueOf(receiveValue));

Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this, Receiver.class);
i.putExtra("new value", receiveValue - 10);
```

Thanks Valen